# How to make a multi-series bar chart in d3?

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, bar-chart

I have a two bar charts that display the same data. One shows one bar for every x-axis label that is the sum of an output set and an input set. The other one i have needs to separate the input and output data into two bars next to each other for each x-axis label.

How i want it to look:
[image]

From what i have seen in other examples the data is merged into a single array then drawn in pairs. I tried to merge both sets into a single one but couldn't get it to work.

Here is how i draw my bars:

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
                .data(options.series[i].data)
                .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("class", function(d) {
                    if (d < 0) {
                        return "bar positive";
                    } else {
                        return "bar negative";
                    }
                })
                .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return Math.abs(yScale(d) - yScale(0));
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    if (d > 0) {
                        return yScale(d);
                    } else {
                        return yScale(0);
                    }
                    // return yScale(d)
                })
                .attr("width", (xScale.bandwidth()))
                .attr("x", function(d, j) {
                    return xScale(options.labels[j])
                })
                .on('mouseover', function(d, j){
                    d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.6);
                    tip.show(d, j);
                })
                .on('mouseout', function(d, j){
                    d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1);
                    tip.hide(d, j);
                })
                .on("click", function(d, j) {
                  zoomInD3(vm, options.labels[j]);
                });
```

I don't want a stacked bar chart, but a side-by-side chart. Any helpful tips?

My data is stored in an array with just the values.

Comment: A [Grouped Bar Chart](https://observablehq.com/@d3/grouped-bar-chart) is what you're looking for. If you could use the example in the link and get back with any issues you face, it'd be easier to debug. Also, please provide a working code snippet with no missing data or use [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) to have a working snippet with what you have as of now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually figured it out. I had combined my two data arrays into a list of objects with a class name.

```
//Combine both sets of data into a list of objects
var combinedList = []
for(var i = 0; i < xAxisLabels.length; i++) {
    var object = {first: options.series[i].data, second: options.series[i].data1}
    combinedList.push(object); //Push object into list
}
//Create container for the bar objects of class bar
var multigraph = svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(combinedList)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "bar")
//Create a rect of the "first" element in object
var bar1 = multigraph.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "first")
            .attr("class","bar negative")
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                return Math.abs(yScale(d.fist) - yScale(0));
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                if (d.first > 0) {
                    return yScale(d.first);
                } else {
                    return yScale(0);
                }
            })
            .attr("width", (xScale.bandwidth()))
            .attr("x", function(d, j) {
                return xScale(options.labels[j])
            })
            .on('mouseover', function(d, j){
                d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.6);
                tip.show(d.first, j);
            })
            .on('mouseout', function(d, j){
                d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1);
                tip.hide(d.first, j);
            })
            .on("click", function(d, j) {
              zoomInD3(vm, options.labels[j]);
            });
//Create a rect of the "second" element in object
var bar2 = multigraph.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "second")
            .attr("class","bar positive")
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                return Math.abs(yScale(d.second) - yScale(0));
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                if (d.second> 0) {
                    return yScale(d.second);
                } else {
                    return yScale(0);
                }
            })
            .attr("width", (xScale.bandwidth()))
            .attr("x", function(d, j) {
                return xScale(options.labels[j])
            })
            .on('mouseover', function(d, j){
                d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.6);
                tip.show(d.second, j);
            })
            .on('mouseout', function(d, j){
                d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1);
                tip.hide(d.second, j);
            })
            .on("click", function(d, j) {
              zoomInD3(vm, options.labels[j]);
            });
```

Still would need to be adjusted on the xAxis based on how far apart the bars would be from each other. Basically having the elements in a callable object the data can become called form the class attribute.

So when checking the inspector for the page elements it will be clear that there is a "g" container that contains two "rect" objects.

Comment: Why do you have to assign each bar to a variable? It doesn't work without that, but I don't understand why it matters.

Comment: @maganthro Since they are referenced by child elements such as "multigraph" they need to be stored in variables.